# Drag and Drop in GWT 2.4

Tags: gwt, gwt2, drag-and-drop

I have a custom widget that is actually an image, and i would like to be able to drag it inside an AbsolutePanel and get its coordinates every time. I would like to use the new DND API from GWT 2.4, but i'm having a hard time to implement it. Can someone propose the basic steps i must take?

Comment: I can see you getting massive points on this question... Nicely done! :-)

Comment: have you tryed smartgwt?

Comment: no smartgwt, i started once to use it and no thanks :) I use this site long time, but to tell you the truth i have not yet found the time or curiocity to check what those points and stars mean...

Comment: Are you about this new DND API? http://gwt-code-reviews.appspot.com/1420811

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The new DnD API introduced with GWT 2.4 doesn't currently support the `AbsolutePanel` (see the implementations of the `HasAllDragAndDropHandlers` interface). Looking at the implementation of `FocusPanel` it shouldn't be too hard to enable it for other panels.

Here's a quick proof of concept on how to solve your problem:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    DragImage image = new DragImage();
    image.setUrl(Resources.INSTANCE.someImage().getSafeUri());
    final DropAbsolutePanel target = new DropAbsolutePanel();
    target.getElement().getStyle().setBorderWidth(1.0, Unit.PX);
    target.getElement().getStyle().setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.SOLID);
    target.getElement().getStyle().setBorderColor("black");
    target.setSize("200px", "200px");

    // show drag over effect
    target.addDragOverHandler(new DragOverHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onDragOver(DragOverEvent event) {
            target.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("#ffa");
        }
    });

    // clear drag over effect
    target.addDragLeaveHandler(new DragLeaveHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onDragLeave(DragLeaveEvent event) {
            target.getElement().getStyle().clearBackgroundColor();
        }
    });

    // enable as drop target
    target.addDropHandler(new DropHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onDrop(DropEvent event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // not sure if the calculation is right, didn't test it really
            int x = (event.getNativeEvent().getClientX() - target.getAbsoluteLeft()) + Window.getScrollLeft();
            int y = (event.getNativeEvent().getClientY() - target.getAbsoluteTop()) + Window.getScrollTop();
            target.getElement().getStyle().clearBackgroundColor();
            Window.alert("x: " + x + ", y:" + y);
            // add image with same URL as the dropped one to absolute panel at given coordinates
            target.add(new Image(event.getData("text")), x, y);
        }
    });

    RootPanel.get().add(image);
    RootPanel.get().add(target);
}
```

And here the custom panel

```
public class DropAbsolutePanel extends AbsolutePanel implements HasDropHandlers, HasDragOverHandlers,
        HasDragLeaveHandlers {

    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addDropHandler(DropHandler handler) {
        return addBitlessDomHandler(handler, DropEvent.getType());
    }

    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addDragOverHandler(DragOverHandler handler) {
        return addBitlessDomHandler(handler, DragOverEvent.getType());
    }

    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addDragLeaveHandler(DragLeaveHandler handler) {
        return addBitlessDomHandler(handler, DragLeaveEvent.getType());
    }
}
```

and image class:

```
public class DragImage extends Image {

    public DragImage() {
        super();
        initDnD();
    }

    private void initDnD() {
        // enables dragging if browser supports html5
        getElement().setDraggable(Element.DRAGGABLE_TRUE);
        addDragStartHandler(new DragStartHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) {
                // attach image URL to drag data
                event.setData("text", getUrl());
            }
        });
    }
}
```